# Queueing a message in JMS, for delayed processing

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

I have a piece of middleware that sits between two JMS queues. From one it reads, processes some data into the database, and writes to the other.

Here is a small diagram to depict the design:

[image]

With that in mind, I have some interesting logic that I would like to integrate into the service.

- Scenario 1: Say the middleware service receives a message from Queue 1, and hits the database to store portions of that message. If all goes well, it constructs a new message with some data, and writes it to Queue 2.
- Scenario 2: Say that the database complains about something, when the service attempts to perform some logic after getting a message from Queue 1.In this case, instead of writing a message to Queue 2, I would re-try to perform the database functionality in incremental timeouts. i.e Try again in 5 sec., then 30 sec, then 1 minute if still down. The catch of course, is to be able to read other messages independently of this re-try. i.e Re-try to process this one request, while listening for other requests.

**With that in mind, what is both the correct and most modern way to construct a future proof solution?**

After reading some posts on the net, it seems that I have several options.

- One, I could spin off a new thread once a new message is received, so that I can both perform the "re-try" functionality and listen to new requests.
- Two, I could possibly send the message back to the Queue, with a delay. i.e If the process failed to execute in the db, write the message to the JMS queue by adding some amount of delay to it.

I am more fond of the first solution, however, I wanted to get the opinion of the community if there is a newer/better way to solve for this functionality in java 7. Is there something built into JMS to support this sort of "send message back for reprocessing at a specific time"?

Comment: I don't think that JMS has a concept of delayed delivery for a simple reason that it does not guarantee delivery timing. The only guarantee that JMS offers is that your message will be delivered eventually. So it can't guarantee message timing or sequence...

Comment: @GermannArlington hmm I see. I suppose threading then it has to be.

Answer (score 0):

JMS 2.0 specification describes the concept of delayed delivery of messages. See "What's new" section of https://java.net/projects/jms-spec/pages/JMS20FinalReleaseMany JMS providers have implemented the delayed delivery feature.

But I wonder how the delayed delivery will help your scenario. Since the database writes have issues, subsequent messages processing and attempt to write to database might end up in same situation. I guess it might be better to sort out issues with database updates and then pickup messages from queue.